# Android Google Maps v2 StreetView rendering errors

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-street-view

I'm using `SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment` together with `SupportMapFragment`in my app. Layout for this is very simple, just `FrameLayout` acting as a container where I add theses fragments at runtime. First classic map fragment and when user click on streetview button I add `SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment` on top of it.

On many devices it acts absolutely fine but on few I encountered errors. StreetView fragment is not rendered at all when I add it in FragmentTransaction, on some devices it renders very very slowly with black screen. When I try to get back to to map by removing StreetView fragment from container it results in crash with followings cat output

```
06-19 12:20:01.937    4636-4636/com.modryandel.debug E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:473)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
        at android.view.SurfaceView$2.onScrollChanged(SurfaceView.java:137)
        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnScrollChanged(ViewTreeObserver.java:607)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1367)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1264)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I discovered that when I leave activity with streetview fragment open and not rendered and after that go back to the activity I've got streetview rendered just fine but crash is still happening.

Testing phones where this happens: 
Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i Android 2.3.6
HTC One X Android 4.0.3
Samsung Galaxy S2, S3 Android 4.1.2

I am sure that these phones has Play services version 4.4.+ as I check it at start.

Does anyone encounter similiar behaviour? Thanks in advance.